# threejs coincident vertices texture discontinued

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I want to make a animated tube with hemisphere ends, the tubular segments is 200. I have the vertices from the first 60 segments to copy the position of a SphereGeometry's upper half part, and the last 60 segments lower half part.

The segments between the upper and lower hemisphere is all copied to the vertices around the sphere's equatorial.

The geometry looks fine, but the spherical environment mapping texture is discontinued at the sphere's equatorial.

[image]

I have my code as below, anyone know how to solve the problem?

```js
var camera, scene, renderer;


   init();
   animate();

   function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 28, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.z = 50;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();


    var nMat = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({side:THREE.DoubleSide,});
    var tube = new DSTube( 200, 30, 10, nMat);

    scene.add( tube.mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //

    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

   }

   function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

   }

   function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );

   }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: #000000;
    overflow: hidden;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r78/three.js"></script>

<script>
   function DSTube( lengthSeg, radiusSeg, radius, material ) {
    //for speed
    this.framerate = 60;
    //center
    this.origin = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.head = this.origin;
    this.tail = this.origin;
    //setup
    this.lengthSeg = lengthSeg;
    this.radiusSeg = radiusSeg;
    this.radius = radius;


    this.pathPoints = [];
    for(var i=0; i<this.lengthSeg; i++) {
     this.pathPoints.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0) );
    }

    // TubeGeometry(path, tubularSegments, radius, radiusSegments, closed)
    this.geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry( new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(this.pathPoints), this.lengthSeg, this.radius, this.radiusSeg, false );
    this.material = material;
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, this.material );

    this.verticeCount = this.geometry.vertices.length;


    //sphere part
    //adjust height segment if needed
    this.sphereHeightSegments = 60;
    //SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength)
    this.headSphere =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( this.radius, this.radiusSeg, this.sphereHeightSegments );
    this.tailSphere =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( this.radius, this.radiusSeg, this.sphereHeightSegments );

    this.sphereVerticeCount = this.headSphere.vertices.length;

    //count for tube hemisphere
    this.headHemisphereVerticeCount = ( this.sphereHeightSegments / 2 + 1 ) *  this.radiusSeg;

    //layer
    this.tubeLayerCount = this.lengthSeg + 1;
    this.headHemisphereLayerCount = this.tailHemisphereLayerCount = this.sphereHeightSegments / 2 + 1;
    this.tailHemisphereStartLayer = this.tubeLayerCount - this.sphereHeightSegments / 2;
    this.middleLayerCount = this.tubeLayerCount - this.headHemisphereLayerCount * 2;


    this.initGeometry();

    // return this.mesh;
   }

   DSTube.prototype.initGeometry = function() {
    this.copyHeadSphere();
    this.copyInitialTubePart();
    this.copyTailSphere();

   }

   DSTube.prototype.copyHeadSphere = function() {
    //copy head hemisphere vertice
    for( var y = 0; y < this.headHemisphereLayerCount; y++ ) {

     for( var x = 0; x < this.radiusSeg; x++ ) {

      if( x == 0 ) {

       var sphereVertex = this.headSphere.vertices[ y * (this.radiusSeg + 1) + x ];
       this.geometry.vertices[ y * this.radiusSeg + x ].copy( sphereVertex );

      } else {

       var sphereVertex = this.headSphere.vertices[ y * (this.radiusSeg + 1) + ( this.radiusSeg - x ) ];
       this.geometry.vertices[ y * this.radiusSeg + x ].copy( sphereVertex );

      }

     }

    }
    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
   }

   DSTube.prototype.copyInitialTubePart = function() {
    //copy head hemisphere vertice
    for( var y = this.headHemisphereLayerCount - 1; y < this.tubeLayerCount ; y++ ) {

     for( var x = 0; x < this.radiusSeg; x++ ) {

      var vertex = this.geometry.vertices[ ( this.headHemisphereLayerCount - 1 ) * this.radiusSeg + x ];
      this.geometry.vertices[ y * this.radiusSeg + x ].copy( vertex );

     }

    }
    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
   }

   DSTube.prototype.copyTailSphere = function() {

    //copy tail hemisphere vertice
    for( var y = this.tailHemisphereStartLayer; y < this.tubeLayerCount; y++ ) {

     for( var x = 0; x < this.radiusSeg; x++ ) {

      if( x == 0 ) {

       var sphereVertex = this.tailSphere.vertices[ ( y - this.middleLayerCount - 1 ) * (this.radiusSeg + 1) + x ];
       this.geometry.vertices[ y * this.radiusSeg + x ].copy( sphereVertex );

      } else {

       var sphereVertex = this.tailSphere.vertices[ ( y - this.middleLayerCount - 1 ) * (this.radiusSeg + 1) + ( this.radiusSeg - x ) ];
       this.geometry.vertices[ y * this.radiusSeg + x ].copy( sphereVertex );

      }

     }

    }
    this.geometry.computeBoundingSphere();
    this.geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    this.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: hi can you create snippet for this... to verify thnkx ..

Comment: sorry that I don't know how to align the code

Comment: you can try in jsfiddle.net... it's easy to decode your code and get result..

Comment: you should create just the parts of the sphere you need by using the extra arguments of the `SphereGeometry` From the API `SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments, phiStart, phiLength, thetaStart, thetaLength)` you are proabaly not correctly copying the sphere attrs. The API is better.